# Получения числа из имена контрола

Tags: c#, wpf, регулярные-выражения

привет есть код.Я в цикле перебираю дочерние картинки грида.У картинок имя типа
"Q1_2"; Числа могут быть от 0 до 14.
Так создаю 2 рандом числа от 0 до 14 и хочу проверить если число  в имени до знака `_` соответствует Row и последнее число в имени после знака `_` соответствует Сolumn то делать какие то действия.

```
int Row = random.Next(0, 14);
int Column = random.Next(0,14);


foreach (var child in chidrens)
{
    i = child as Image;
    if (i is Image)
        {
           //Вот тут получить числа из имени и сравнить с рандомными числами

        }
        else
        {
           //иначе
        }
}
```

Думаю сделать так

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}_\d{2}";
```

но я так понимаю тбудет искать 2 цифры у меня есть и одна цифра
это что делать

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{1}_\d{1}";
```

Подскажите как по нормальному это сделать

Comment: Ты можешь изменить имя картинок? Сделать такими `001002` Тогда можно будет считывать из строки первые и последние 3 цифры - твои номера.

Comment: только из цифр нельзя делать имя Я поэтому и добавил букву

Comment: тогда используй q001002 и бери следующие цифры.

Comment: непоянтно почему число из имени контрола? Ты можешь сделать объект из класса?: имя контрола  - его номер - его второй номер. `obj_Q1_2.name obj_Q1_2_.n1 obj_Q1_2_.n2` и из него брать твои данные

Comment: Контролы помимо `Name` еще имеют такое свойство как `Tag`, в него можно записывать необходимые вам номера картинок, безо всяких начальных букв и прочего ненужного мусора. Можно сделать сквозную нумерацию картинок или сделать нумерацию из двузначного числа - для номеров строки и столбца.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай проще. Создай массив на 3 элемента. Например string[] mass = new string[3];
mass = i.Split('_','Q');
Разрезаешь имя файла на  3 элемента и потом сравниваешь элементы массива. 0- пусто 1 - первое число 2- второе число. И все) А то еще регулярки суешь)) ужс)